# Условное форматирование для двух столбцов

Tags: excel

Есть 3 столбца: `A`, `B`, `C`.

Если суммарное количество знаков в ячейках одной строки столбцов `A` и `B` больше N, при этом в ячейке столбца `C` определенный текст, то закрасить ячейки столбцов `A` и `B` этой строки.

Написал правило условного форматирования для диапазона `=$A:$B`:

```
=И((ДЛСТР(A1)+ДЛСТР(B1))>5;C1="текст")
```

При выполнении условия ожидаю получить закрашенные ячейки в двух столбцах (`A` и `B`), но закрашивается только `A`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не закреплены столбцы в ссылках. При этом для столбца `В` диапазон сместится и будет `B:D`.

Исправляем:

```
=И(ДЛСТР($A1)+ДЛСТР($B1)>5;$C1="текст")

=ЕСЛИ($C1="текст";ДЛСТР($A1&$B1)>5)
```